# how to apply JQueryUI checkboxradio to all Checkboxes in entire ASP Web App

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have number of `CheckBox`s in my ASP Webform app. I would like to apply `JQuery UI` `checkboxradio()` for all check boxes in my app.

To do so, I have placed below code in my `Site.Master` file but not working whereas the same code is working if place inside individual `.ASPX` files

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").checkboxradio();
```

Since, I have many `.ASPX` files, please suggest me a way to place this in `Site.Master`.

Here is sample server generated `HTML` file.

```
    <label for="CentreContent_AllHSNCodes">Display all HSN Codes  </label>
<input id="CentreContent_AllHSNCodes" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$CentreContent$AllHSNCodes" onclick="javascript:setTimeout(&#39;__doPostBack(\&#39;ctl00$CentreContent$AllHSNCodes\&#39;,\&#39;\&#39;)&#39;, 0)" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to add a script that will be applicable throughout all of your pages?
If so, first add a script in you scripts folder with

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").checkboxradio();
```

then go to the BundleConfig.cs folder located usually in the App_Start folder, then add the script directory to the first bundle list such as :

```
"~/Scripts/YourScriptName.js"
```

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

First one: You defined `id="AllHSNCodes"` of field but when page load in browser in this time new `id` is generating. Your new id is `CentreContent_AllHSNCodes`. If you use new id in JQuery then it will work. Otherwise you have to use `'input[type="checkbox"]'`.

```
$( function() {
        $('#CentreContent_AllHSNCodes').checkboxradio();
      });
```

or

```
$( function() {
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').checkboxradio();
  });
```